# why my karma test does not run a service's 'then' part?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

My test looks like,

```
it("init the service", function(){

      console.log(baseHttp);

      baseHttp.getFire().then(function(response){

        console.log(1);
        expect(true).toBe(false);

      }, function(response){});

  });
```

This test passed and the console only showed what baseHttp is, but did not show 1. This means the then part does not run.

My service is like,

```
testApp.service("baseHttp", function($http, $q){

  this.getFire = function(){


    console.log(2);
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log(3);
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: "http://www.google.com"
    }).then(function(response){
      console.log(4);
      deferred.resolve(response);
    },function(response){
      deferred.reject(resposne);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  };
})
```

When it is karma'ed, 2 and 3 were outputted. 4 was not. But, when I run it in the web app (web page), it does work. Only that it cannot be karma'ed.

Comment: Because you haven't said the $httpBackend (that is mocked in unit tests) what to do when receiving the request, and you haven't flushed it either. Read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend. Also read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/ and the following article, because you're using a promise antipattern.

Comment: Thanks. Adding $httpBackend works.